# Jasperreport server 7.1.0 returns 400 error code (Bad Request)

Tags: jasperserver

I have a report to print some envelopes and its only parameter is a collection of strings that are a concatenation of four numeric values separated by semicolon (and tried with underscores also) in order to print the correct combination of ids, that is why four simple integer parameters does not work or I have to generate them one by one. I did what it is described in the [documentation](https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/849516/passing-collection-jasper-server-restv2-api) pages 93-94, so my URL to generate the report is similar to this:

http://jasperserver:8050/jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/Reports/Envelope_No_10.pdf?cId=1;12496;1;7819&cId=1;23373;1;18536&username=myusername&password=mypassword

I have noted that when I sent the GET request without the parameters (except the username and password) the report is shown as a blank envelope, which is correct. However, if I set the parameter no matter if it is only one or many I get a 400 error. As I said I tried separating the numbers with underscores and semicolons with no avail and also encoding the parameters. I tested it Jasper Studio using the server's very same report and the parameter must be defined as ['1;12496;1;7819','1;23373;1;18536'] in order to work as expected.

If I use a post method call Jasper Server returns a 405 error code: method not allowed.

What I am doing wrong?, is there another way to achieve the desired result?,  is it a bug? the usage is the same as the documentation states as far as I know.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I finally, make the report work and the solution was to do these changes:

1. Making the parameter a java.util.Collection of integers, not strings as originally was. Of course it means that the SQL involved must be adjusted accordingly
2. To send the parameters I has to send them as the documentation said, so cId=3243232&cId=7437483, values separated by commas does not work. However, if the parameter only takes one value the report fails. For those cases I had to add a dumb parameter (&cId=0) and into the report if the value is 0 then does not print. This is a dirty solution, may you give me a better one.
3. Using in the SQL WHERE clause as the official syntax said $X{IN, table_field, JR_Param_Name} and defining JR_Param_Name as java.util.Collection of Integer or Long, not String as I said.

At the end seemed that JR cannot manage a collection of Strings as parameters, maybe because the single commas involved in order to work correctly in the SQL IN clause. I tried the IN ($P!{JR_Param_Name}) - the parenthesis are important; otherwise the expression is not accepted - as in some solutions in Jasper Community gave, but it does not work, neither sending a JSON formatted parameters using GET or POST.

Hoping this answer helps someone trying to achieve the same functionality using Jasper Reports.